# Transmitting data before needing it between two page in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I want to transmit data between two page of my app, usually I don't have any problem with the syntax `this.props.navigation.state.params...` but in this case the problem is that itemCategory is undefined because my first page (initial route) is `HomeScreen` and my second page is `CategoryListScreen`. So what happen exactly :

1. The user launch the app and land in the HomeScreen
2. In the constructor i'm trying to modify the state category with itemCategory which IS NOT defined for the moment

   this.state = {
             categories: this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory,
             restaurantData: [],
           }
3. The app crashed because this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory is undefined

I have tried to change the  initial route by `CategoryListScreen` and the data is correctly set inside my state category of my HomeScreen page because is it now my second page.

So what I want to know is how to set the variable category without making crash the app...

*The `CategoryListScreen` is used by the user to choose which type of food he want to eat, so I can make a call to my API to only display the restaurant having this category of food.*

```js
/*Beginning CategoryListScreen*/

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FlatList, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment'
import axios from '../../interceptor/tokenInterceptor'
import Hamburger from '../../components/Hamburger/Hamburger'
import styles from './styles'

const menuData = [
    { 
        id: '1',
        title: 'Burger',
        image: require('../../assets/images/burger.jpg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '2',
        title: 'Pizza',
        image: require('../../assets/images/pizza.jpeg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '3',
        title: 'Sushi',
        image: require('../../assets/images/sushi.jpg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '4',
        title: 'Tacos',
        image: require('../../assets/images/tacos.jpeg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '5',
        title: 'Chinois',
        image: require('../../assets/images/plat_chinois.jpg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '6',
        title: 'Français',
        image: require('../../assets/images/plat_français.jpg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '7',
        title: 'Mexicain',
        image: require('../../assets/images/mexicain.jpg'),
      },
      { 
        id: '8',
        title: 'Italien',
        image: require('../../assets/images/italien.jpg'),
      },
]

class CategoryListScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Menu',
    headerLeft: (
      <Hamburger
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.openDrawer()
        }}
      />
    ),
  })

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      restaurantData: [],
    }
  }

  onPress = itemCategory => {
    // console.log('category : ', itemCategory);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {itemCategory})
    // console.log(item);
    // this.getRestaurantByCategories(item)
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPress(item.title)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.photo} source={item.image}/>
        <View style={styles.overlay} />
        <Text numberOfLines={3} style={styles.title}>
          {item.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        vertical
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        numColumns={2}
        data={menuData}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
      />
    )
  }
}

CategoryListScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }),
}

export default CategoryListScreen

/*End CategoryListScreen*/


/*Beginning HomeScreen*/

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} from 'react-native'
import _ from 'lodash'
import Hamburger from '../../components/Hamburger/Hamburger'
import ShoppingCartButton from '../../components/ShoppingCartButton/ShoppingCartButton'
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment'
import axios from '../../interceptor/tokenInterceptor'
import styles from './styles'

const categoriesData = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Burger',
    image: require('../../assets/images/burger.jpg'),
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Pizza',
    image: require('../../assets/images/pizza.jpeg'),
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Sushi',
    image: require('../../assets/images/sushi.jpg'),
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Tacos',
    image: require('../../assets/images/tacos.jpeg'),
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    title: 'Chinois',
    image: require('../../assets/images/plat_chinois.jpg'),
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    title: 'Cuisine',
    image: require('../../assets/images/plat_français.jpg'),
  },
]

/**
 * Construit le component catégorie en haut de la page
 */
ItemCategory = ({title, image}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={image} style={styles.categoryItemPhoto} />
      <Text style={styles.categoryItemTitle}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

/**
 * Construit les composant restaurant
 */
ItemRestaurant = ({id, title, image, distance, categories}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {/* <Text>{id}</Text> */}
      {/* <Image source={{uri: `data:image/png;base64,${image}`}}  style={styles.foodPhoto}/> */}
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textRestaurant}>
        distance depuis votre position : {distance}m
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.textRestaurant}>Catégories : {`${categories}`}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Home',
    headerLeft: () => (
      <Hamburger
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.openDrawer()
        }}
      />
    ),
    headerRight: () => (
      <ShoppingCartButton
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('CartScreen')
        }}
      />
    ),
  })

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // if (this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory === undefined) {
    //   console.log('dans le if')
    //   this.state = {
    //     restaurantData: [],
    //   }
    // } else {
    //   this.state = {
    //     categories: this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory,
    //     restaurantData: [],
    //   }
    // }
    // if (this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory === undefined) {
    //   console.log('je suis undefined');
    // }
    this.state = {
          // categories: this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory,
          categories: this.props.navigation.getParam('itemCategory', 'NO_VALUE'),
          // categories: _.get(this.props, 'navigation.state.params.itemCategory'),
          restaurantData: [],
        }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('dans le componentdidmount : ', this.state.categories);
    this.getRestaurant()
  }

  /**
   * Récupère la liste de tous les restaurants à moins de 30km du user
   */
  getRestaurant = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${environment.apiDevUrl}/restaurant/visible`,
      })
      this.setState({
        restaurantData: res.data,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  getCategories = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${environment.apiDevUrl}/restaurant/category/Pizza`,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Affiche seulement les restaurants en fonction de la catégorie choisi par le user
   */
  getRestaurantByCategories = async (item) => {
    console.log('item : ',item);
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${environment.apiDevUrl}/restaurant/category`,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: {
          category: item
        }
      })
      this.setState({restaurantData: res.data})
      console.log('restaurantData : ', this.state.restaurantData);
      return res.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  onPressCategoryItem = item => {
    this.getRestaurantByCategories(item.title)
  }

  onPressRestaurantItem = item => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('RestaurantDetailScreen', {item})
  }

  initCartFromPersistentStore() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperCart:key')
      .then(res => {
        if (res != null) {
          const array = JSON.parse(res)
          console.log(array)
          this.props.navigation.dispatch({type: 'Override', items: array})
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Promise is rejected with error: ${error}`)
      })
  }

  renderCategoryItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressCategoryItem(item)}>
      <View style={styles.categoryItemContainer}>
        <ItemCategory image={item.image} title={item.title} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )

  renderRestaurantItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressRestaurantItem(item.restaurant.id)}>
      <View style={styles.foodItemContainer}>
        <ItemRestaurant
          // id={item.restaurant.id}
          image={item.restaurant.image}
          title={item.restaurant.nom}
          distance={item.distance}
          categories={item.restaurant.categorie}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )

  render() {
    console.log('dans le render : ', this.state.categories);
    // const categoryFromList = this.props.navigation.state.params.itemCategory
    // console.log('category dans homescreen : ',categoryFromList);
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}> Catégories populaires</Text>
        <View style={styles.categories}>
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            initialNumToRender={4}
            data={categoriesData}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={this.renderCategoryItem}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.title}> Restaurants </Text>
        <View style={styles.foods}>
          <FlatList
            initialNumToRender={2}
            data={this.state.restaurantData}
            renderItem={this.renderRestaurantItem}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.restaurant.id}`}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

HomeScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }),
}


/*End HomeScreen*/
```

Comment: Which version of react-navigation you are using?

Comment: You can simply use 
this.state = { categories: this.props.navigation.state.params?.itemCategory ?? "YOUR_DEFAULT_DATA", restaurantData: [], }

Comment: Ok but now my categories is never updated it's stay on the default value and i use the version 4.2.2 of react-navigation

Comment: Simply in HomeScreen's componentDidMount, you can check that itemCategory and if you found that you can setState otherwise you can set it as default one

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add [Lodash](http://lodash.com) module and do something like:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

....
this.state = {
  categories: _.get(this.props, 'navigation.state.params.itemCategory'),
  restaurantData: []
}
...
```

This way your app won't crash.

Comment: I have tried with another method so I don't have to add another package to my project, i have make this : `categories: this.props.navigation.getParam('itemCategory', 'NO_VALUE')`, who return a default value just like lodash. But now the problem is my value is always the default one, it's never updated... I have tried lodash and this the result is the same

Comment: When you move to the `CategoryListScreen`, are you sending the `itemCategory` as parameter? Are you using react navigation?

Comment: Yes I use react-navigation and no I don't send back itemCategory in `CategoryListScreen` i just send it to `HomeScreen`

Comment: Can you share your code at JSFiddle? Even if it doesn't runs,  just to check?

Comment: I have had the jsfiddle

Comment: You can try to add the `componentWillReceiveProps`, check if the `itemCategory` changed and update state.
Looks like on `HomeScreen` you are setting it on constructor, but if the category change you won't detect. That's why you need to implement `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Something like this ? `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.itemCategory!==this.props.itemCategory){
      this.setState({categories: itemCategory });
      console.log('dans le componentWillReceiveProps : ',this.state.categories);
    }
  }`

Comment: Exactly like that!

Comment: No I have tried but it's not working, however if I passed a function inside my stackNavigator it's working but unfortunately I automatically navigate to the page CategoryListScreen...